# Filtered FK select ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

On one page of the website, I have to filter a foreign key.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxAGK.png)

This is my page and I only want the customer vlan without a disconnect date to show up.

Connection controller:

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    ViewData["Customercode"] = new SelectList(_db.Customers, "Id",   "CompanyName");
    ViewData["Customervlancode"] = new SelectList(_db.CustomerVlans, "Id",  "Usage");
    ViewData["Switchcode"] = new SelectList(_db.Switchzs, "Id", "SwitchName");

    return View();
}
```

Connection create view

```
<div class="mb-3">
    <label asp-for="DisconnectionDate"></label>
    <input type="date" asp-for="DisconnectionDate" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="DisconnectionDate" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Customervlancode" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="Customervlancode" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Customervlancode"></select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Customercode" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="Customercode" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Customercode"></select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Switchcode" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="Switchcode" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Switchcode"></select>
</div>
```

Connection model

```
public class Connection
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SwitchPortNumber{ get; set; }
    public string Duplex { get; set; }
    public string VoiceVlanNumber { get; set; }
    public string PhoneMACAddress { get; set; }
    public string PhoneExtension { get; set; }
    public string Purpose { get; set; }
    public string StickyPort { get; set; }
    public string AdditionalConfiguration { get; set; }
    public string Remark { get; set; }
    public string ActualUser { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionDate { get; set; }
    public string? DisconnectionDate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Customervlan")]
    public int? Customervlancode { get; set; }
    public virtual Customervlan? Customervlan { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Customer")]
    public int? Customercode { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer? Customer { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Switch")]
    public int? Switchcode { get; set; }
    public virtual Switchz? Switch { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DataOutlet")]
    public int? DataOutletcode { get; set; }
    public virtual DataOutlet? DataOutlet { get; set; }
}
```

Maybe there special method I can add to

```
ViewData["Customervlancode"] = new SelectList(_db.CustomerVlans, "Id", "Usage");
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDPvD.png)

I only want options to show up in my select field if the `disconnectdate` is empty NULL/Empty.

I thought the `Disconnectdate` would be visible in inspect element so i could hide the options but it does not show up.

I tried to add `Disconnectdate` to

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    ViewData["Customercode"] = new SelectList(_db.Customers, "Id", "CompanyName");
    ViewData["Customervlancode"] = new SelectList(_db.CustomerVlans, "Id", "Usage","DisconnecDate ");
    ViewData["Switchcode"] = new SelectList(_db.Switchzs, "Id", "SwitchName");

    return View();
}
```